# Support of Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have a quesion about the confusing using of the term "support of schemes" in Lemma 2.3.41 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 53):

[image]

I know that the "support of a sheaf $F$ on a scheme $X$" is generally defined as the subset $S$ of $X$ so that for every $x \in S$ we have for the stalk $F_x \neq 0$. Why is this definition with the definition above the red line compatible (here for the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}_A ^n$ support $=$ underlying topol. space)?

Comment: Because for a closed subscheme $X \subset \Bbb P^n$ the support of $\mathcal O_X$ is exactly $X$.

Comment: (More precisely the support of $i_* \mathcal O_X$ where $i : X \to \Bbb P^n$ is the inclusion but it's very commun to write it simply $\mathcal O_X$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $i:Z \rightarrow X$ be a closed subscheme.  This entails several things: $Z$ is a scheme whose underlying topological space is a closed subset of $X$, and $i$ is a morphism of schemes such that $i^{\#}: \mathcal O_X \rightarrow i_{\ast} \mathcal O_Z$ is surjective as a morphism of sheaves on $X$.

In your notes, the support of this closed subscheme means the underlying space of $Z$ (I'll follow convention and identify $Z$ with its underlying space).  And if $F$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$, the support of $F$ is defined to be the set of $x \in X$ such that $F_x \neq 0$.

The connection between these two notions of support is this: $Z$ is exactly the support of the sheaf $i^{\ast} \mathcal O_Z$.

If $x \in Z$, then $(i_{\ast} \mathcal O_Z)_x$ is the direct limit of rings $\mathcal O_Z(V \cap Z)$, where $V$ runs through the set of open sets in $X$ containing $x$, ordered by reverse inclusion.  But then $V \cap Z$ runs through the direct limit of open sets in $Z$ containing $x$, so this is just $\mathcal O_{Z,x} \neq 0$.

If $x \not\in Z$, then since $X - Z$ is open, we can shrink the direct system of open neighborhoods of $x$ to only include those contained in $X - Z$, and obtain the same direct limit.  But for every such open neighborhood $V$, we have $\mathcal O_Z(V \cap Z) = \mathcal O_Z(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: Hi. Thank for the detailed unswer. There is one step which isn't clear to me. 
If you let $V \cap Z$ run through the direct limit of open sets in $Z$ containing $x$ why $\mathcal O_{Z,x} \neq 0$?

 The properties of $i ^{\#}$ (as inclusion) providing $\mathcal O_Z(V \cap Z) = O_X(V \cap Z)$ so $\mathcal O_{Z,x} = \mathcal O_{X,x}$ if $x \in Z$. But I don't see any argument that for every $x \in X$ we should have $\mathcal O_{X,x} \neq 0$

Comment: Let $U = \textrm{Spec}(R)$ be an affine open subset of $Z$ containing $x$.  Then $x$ can be identified as a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $R$, and $\mathcal O_{Z,x} = \mathcal O_{Z|U,x} = R_{\mathfrak p}$.  Since $U$ is nonempty, $R$ is not zero, and hence $R_{\mathfrak p} \neq 0$.

Comment: I should also point out that while $(i_{\ast} \mathcal O_Z)_x = \mathcal O_{Z,x}$, in general $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is NOT isomorphic to $\mathcal O_{Z,x}$.  (Example: $I$ an ideal of a ring $A$, $Z = \textrm{Spec}(A/I)$ is a closed subscheme of $X = \textrm{Spec}(A)$; if $x = \mathfrak p$ is a prime of $A$ lying in $Z$, then $\mathcal O_{X,x} = A_{\mathfrak p}$, while $\mathcal O_{Z,x} = A_{\mathfrak p}/I_{\mathfrak p}$)